# twitvid video upload issue "code": "1002", "msg": "No file specified to upload"

Tags: php, video, file-upload, twitter

I am uploading video on twitvid using its official php library.
http://www.martin-gardner.co.uk/twitvid/twitvid.class.example.php#embedvideo

But when I upload a video it is return error like this.

```
include_once('twitvid.class.php');
$Tv = new Twitvid;
$Tv->username = 'iphoneteamds@gmail.com';
$Tv->password = 'ds#123456';
$login_test = $Tv->authenticate_it();
$Tv->token="62BE4CB70D9A49100A1C6A175C8ED3E5";



if($_FILES['file']){
    pr($_FILES);
    $myfile = $_FILES['file'];
    //$myfile = fread(fopen($_FILES ['file']['tmp_name'], 'r'), $_FILES['file']['size']);
    $my_upload = $Tv->upload_video($myfile,"test","test1");
    pr($my_upload);
}
```

and ehre is my upload video method

```
function upload_video($media, $message="", $title="", $format='json', $playlist_id="", $vidResponse_parent="", $yt_username="", $yt_password="", $user_tags="", $geo_latitude="", $geo_longitude="", $tags="", $description="")
        {
            $request = 'https://im.twitvid.com/api/upload ';
            if($this->token !== ""){ 
                $postargs = "token=".$this->token."&format=".$format."&message=".$message."&playlist_id=".$playlist_id."&vidResponse_parent=".$vidResponse_parent."&yt_username=".$yt_username;
                $postargs.= "&yt_password=".$yt_password."&user_tags=".$user_tags."&geo_latitude=".$geo_latitude."&geo_longitude=".$geo_longitude."&tags=".$tags;
                $postargs.= "&description=".$description."&title=".$title."&media=".$media;
            }else {
                $postargs = "username=".$this->username."&password=".$this->password."&format=".$format."&message=".$message."&playlist_id=".$playlist_id."&vidResponse_parent=".$vidResponse_parent."&yt_username=".$yt_username;
                $postargs.= "&yt_password=".$yt_password."&user_tags=".$user_tags."&geo_latitude=".$geo_latitude."&geo_longitude=".$geo_longitude."&tags=".$tags;
                $postargs.= "&description=".$description."&title=".$title."&media=".$media;
            }
            return $this->process($request,$postargs);
        }
```

Please help me to get it resolve and upload video

My form is as below

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and result is as below.

```
{
"rsp": {
"stat": "fail",
"err": {
"code": "1002",
"msg": "No file specified to upload"
}
}
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Marty, I wrote the twitvid class, 
it looks like, you could be just sending the file name to the upload method, and not the binary file data?

Anyway... its been a while since that class was updated!

I've updated the class to version 1.3

it can be found on the site: http://martin-gardner.co.uk/twitvid/

Its a total re-write of the class from the ground up to comply with all the changes twitvid(Telly as it will be known) has made to the api and features they offer.

download the latest version of the class, there's a demo page included in the download which is a copy of the [example page](http://martin-gardner.co.uk/twitvid/twitvid.class_v1.3/) where you can see the basic code used to upload...

Comment: I'm getting the same result as the OP. Trying to use it from C#.
POST /api/uploadAndPost HTTP/1.1

Host: im.twitvid.com

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=635075109150857360

Content-Length: 32666

Expect: 100-continue

Connection: Keep-Alive



HTTP/1.1 100 Continue



{"token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABK1RQAAAAAAbHuJfDq3hPokzQiWFZnDqW7iN2o%3DcT5arBjqsKXOIYrv2sIljnlMbH4bSqxODw5EKoqgLcw"}



Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MEDIA"; filename="test.avi"

Content-Type: video/avi

Content-Transfer-Encoding: utf8

Comment: BTW, the video is really 32k, for test purpose.

Comment: A sample XML or json request would have been great. :)